# SearchVew не работает поиск

Tags: android, android-search-view

Сделал такую реализаци :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener searchQueryListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            search(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            search(newText);
            return true;
        }

        public void search(String query) {
            fruitsSearch = filter(fruitsList, query);
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter((ArrayList) fruitsSearch);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    };

    private static List<Fruit> filter(List<Fruit> models, String query) {
        final String lowerCaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<Fruit> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Fruit model : models) {
            final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(lowerCaseQuery)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

Поиск не реагирует на ввод текста. Что нужно еще сделать, или исправить ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы сделали OnQueryTextListener, но не подписались на него. Добавьте следующее

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener)
```